# PHPMailer store finished mail

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm searching for a good way to store the e-mail generated by PHPMailer, 
in a database instead of sending it out directly via SMTP. 
The reason for doing this is, that mails are getting sent via customer provided mail servers, which will probably be unreliable. So that's why I would like to queue mails in the database instead of directly sending them.

The obvious idea would be to store PHPMailers internal $MIMEHeader, $MIMEBody and similar variables and then later put them back into the PHPMailer object.
Unfortunatly this isn't really possible, because most of these variables have protected-access modifiers set on them without any other way of accessing them.

I thought about doing things like Reflection to change the access modifiers to public, but that sounds like a crude hack, which is prone to breaking...
Also: I don't really want to modify PHPMailer itself, to be able to still update PHPMailer.

Serializing the whole PHPMailer object was another idea, but that would be a little bit impractical, because I'd need to make sure that (for example) attachments in the filesystem are still there when sending the mail.

Comment: The simplest with way with little resource overhead....just store the variables used for PHPMailer into a DB rather than saving the entire email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get hold of a complete message without sending it by doing this:

```
$mail->preSend();
$message = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();
```

You can drive the SMTP class by itself if you want to submit a pre-built message, but it's not especially straightforward - you are better off following the other suggestions of storing the parameters rather than the pre-built message.

Being able to set headers and body directly would imply that PHPMailer contains a complete MIME parser, and that's just not its job. Also getting around the protected access is not sufficient because calling the `send` function would cause all your changes to be overwritten because the message is only built at send time (which is why those properties are protected in the first place - they are for internal use). In short, you're approaching this the wrong way.

As others have said though - you're queuing in the wrong place - this is what mail servers are for, they are very good at it, and you *really* don't want to write your own MTA. This is what I do, and I have no problem sending a million message per hour - my MTA takes care of all the reliability issues.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm searching for a good way to store the e-mail generated by PHPMailer

Perhaps it would be sufficient to store just data you build your mail content from (even as serialized arrays, JSON whatever). Then when needed, you can build the mail again and resend.

> which will probably be unreliable

By the same logic your code will probably be buggy.

Jokes aside, once `send()` returned success, it's not your problem what will happen with the mail delivery. If it will fail, then it's not you who should fix it as the culprit is outside your code. Just add "reliable mail server" to your app's requirements :)